# Hibernate Query#setParameterList, when query parameters are entities

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate's Query#setParameterList has a variant that accept Type as the last parameter:

```
setParameterList(String name, Collection values, Type type)
```

If the parameterList is a list of entity instances, what type should we provide?

I know we can supply entity ids as parameter values. I also know that type is optional. But what if I **want** to provide the entity instances, and I **want** to provide a type? Is it possible?

(For setting a single parameter, there is Query#setEntity(name, value).)